# Formula for quadratic variation of a general Levy process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, levy-processes, quadratic-variation

Let $X$ be a one-dimensional Levy process with generating triplet $(\gamma,\sigma^2,\nu)$. Is there a formula for the quadratic variation for this process without further restrictions?

In the book *Mathematical Finance* by Eberlein and Kallsen (2019) it is stated that
$$
[X,X]_t = \sigma^2t + \sum_{s\leq t}(\Delta X_s)^2
$$
for the above defined Levy process X, but in all other resources I have found so far, only ''weaker'' examples were given, such as quadratic variations of Levy processes without a Brownian part.

It makes sense to me, that if $X$ has only finitely many jumps, by the Levy-Ito decomposition, the quadratic variation is just the sum of the quadratic variation of the Brownian part and the quadratic variation of a compound Poisson process, which then yields the above expression. But in the case of infinitely many jumps, does the sum even exist/converge?

Comment: Pls refer to the book: Philip E. Protter, *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations*, 2nd Ed, Springer-Verlag, 2005.  p.66.